# Is there a way to debug Python code which runs on a `multiprocessing.Process`?

Tags: python, debugging, multiprocessing

What I would like is to be able to step-debug code that runs in a separate process using the `multiprocessing` package.

I remember looking for a solution about a year ago and not finding one. I was told to just do a lot of logging, but of course it is an inferior method. So maybe someone came up with a solution in the meantime? For example, some mechanism for making the newly-spawned process connect with the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

You could start the process You need to debug manually, without using the Process interface on this process.

Comment: I don't understand at all, can you clarify?

Comment: Comment out starting the process You want to debug but make it a commandline option to run only this process (with the debugger enabled). Start the program (it will probably get stuck as the process You disabled doesn't run ;) ). Then, start the program with the commandline argument. What You have now on the console is a process You needed running under the debugger. On the second console in the background everything else is running. That way the debugged process doesn't use multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [WingIDE](http://wingware.com/) useful.  Its debugger is really nice, and it even supports debugging remote processes with some minimal instrumentation to the code being debugged.  It's not free, but well worth the cost, IMHO. (I'm not affiliated with Wingware in any way, just a satisfied customer...)

To enable remote debugging in Wing, you need to copy the file `wingdbstub.py` to the same directory as the app you want to debug, and import it at the spot in your code you want debugging to begin.  (This is covered fairly thoroughly in the [WingIDE docs](http://www.wingware.com/doc/debug/importing-the-debugger).)

If you take [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227808/how-can-i-send-python-multiprocessing-process-output-to-a-tkinter-gui/4298569#4298569) and modify the `myfunc()` method to look as follows:

```
def myfunc(conn, commands):
    import wingdbstub
    # ... remainder same as original example
```

you should be able to launch WingIDE, set a breakpoint immediately after the `import` line, then launch the example script from a console.  It should automatically connect to Wing and stop at your breakpoint.

You might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063482/remote-debugging-with-wingide/4300007#4300007) helpful if you have any problems getting the debug connection to work. (The WingIDE docs also do a decent job of covering connection problems.)

Comment: I'm an avid Wing user myself. But I don't know how to make it debug separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than starting your function or class via Process, just call it directly and debug as you normally would.

Comment: The point of the program is that it launches processes automatically to handle jobs, so your suggestion would defeat the purpose.